# Is it ever explained what dangers Thrawn's people were guarding against?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, yuuzhan-vong

In Zahn's "Specter of the Past"/"Vision of the Future", Mara Jade gets an offer from Baron Fel to join Thrawn's Empire of the Hand in their mission to protect the galaxy from some Really Bad threat(s).

Was it ever elaborated in EU or any canon what that threat was? Yuuzhan Vong? Was it ever elaborated in any source?

So far I recall 2 big threats they were dealing with - Vagaari and Ssi-ruuvi (who were under some influence from Yuuzhan Vong at one point).

Comment: Why does this question have a bounty? It answers itself, the Chiss were scared of the Yuuzhan Vong. That's the answer. It's in the question.

Comment: @DKuntz2 - I'd like some... I donno... references or one of them quotes may be. Not sure what the reason for bounty was though

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Admiral_Thrawn#Thrawn_and_the_Yuuzhan_Vong

Comment: Cthulhu, obviously.

Comment: @DKuntz2 I put the bounty because this question is not properly answered. Yes the answer is in the question, but what DVK is asking for a confirmation. Keep in mind that it's not everybody that read all and everything in Star Wars EU. In my case, "Specter of the Past" and "Vision of the Future" are the 2 last novel I read, that's why I find it a interesting question. Anyway, if you (or anyone faster than you) answer the question with quoted excerpt of the Wikipedia article you linked, you will get some easy rep. You could Also use : http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Empire_of_the_Hand#Formation

Comment: @DavRob60 - you're welcome to post an answer (Not sure if the bounty will apply to your own answer or not), since nobody else is willing to take a shot.

Comment: @DVK I though about that, but I will lose my bounty. (sigh) I will do this on my lunch hour if nobody else do it before that.

Comment: @DavRob60 - If you prefer, I'll try to answer. Based on the comments, there's no weird info I somehow didn't know.

Comment: @DVK, ok I made the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TLDR, yes it was the Yuuzhan Vong, and the source of this information is the [Outbound Flight novel by Timothy Zahn](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Outbound_Flight_%28novel%29).

First from the Wikipedia page for [Grand Admiral Thrawn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Admiral_Thrawn#Thrawn_and_the_Yuuzhan_Vong)

> [...] In the novel Outbound Flight by Timothy Zahn, **the Chiss knew of the Yuuzhan Vong long before the Republic or Empire.**
>
> [...] Sidious had foreseen this new alien threat and saw it critical to prevent the large Jedi and Republic citizen populace from being captured and interrogated by the Vong. Such an occurrence would give the Vong a critical informational advantage over the Republic and the Chiss, perhaps throwing off chances of a successful defense against the alien species.
>
> [...] When Thrawn eventually returned to the Unknown Regions, having been made a Grand Admiral by Emperor Palpatine, he carved out a huge empire, going by the name Empire of the Hand. When Luke and Mara Jade Skywalker investigated Thrawn's personal fortress, they encountered the Imperial officer who had first brought Thrawn to the Empire - Admiral Voss Parck. Parck indicated that Thrawn's campaign against the Republic was not solely out of a personal desire to gain power, but **to prepare the galaxy against a coming threat - likely the Vong.** Later, after the rediscovery of the Outbound Flight remains, Luke and Mara Jade Skywalker speculated **that part of the reason behind the Chiss desire for an excuse to wage war on the Vagaari was because the Vagaari had already made contact with the threat (probably the Yuuzhan Vong) and had allied with them.**

Also in [Wookieepedia's Empire of the Hand article](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Empire_of_the_Hand) cite the same book, and subtly indicate the reason of it's creation through a link in a mention of an "*unknown and powerful threat*" that point to the Yuuzhan Vong article. The Peacekeeper of the Unknown Regions section cites pirates and Ssi-ruuk as others threats, but they are not the purpose of the Empire of the Hand.

Comment: If you add a quote from the book itself, I'll assign my own bounty to this answer.

Comment: @DVK They [appear to be unnamed](http://books.google.ca/books?id=nAmtRLeaBrMC&lpg=PP1&dq=Outbound%20Flight%20by%20Timothy%20Zahn&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=Yuuzhan%20&f=false) in this book...

Answer (score 2):

Also the Killiks. they were a threat the chiss were aware of.

Comment: Eh, they weren't really a threat at the time, the Chiss were just aware of them being there. It wasn't until after Raynor Thul was 'assimilated' that the Killiks became an issue, so, waaaaaaaaay after Thrawn.